# Is there an efficient way to add hours to a DateTime field within a list of entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm selecting a list of entities that have the following properties:

1. **id** *(int)*
2. **code** *(varchar)*
3. **created** *(datetime)*

I am selecting these entities using a lambda expression like so:

```
var codes = context.ProgramCodes.ToList();
```

The entity's `created` field is a UTC timestamp, however I want it to be UTC +4.

Apart from the obvious approach of looping over each entity in the list and adding 4 hours to the `created` field, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What about executing a raw sql command to your underlying database? https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: *"however I want it to be UTC +4"* this sounds like an x/y problem. why do you want them stored this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

Don't convert it.

Your systems (UI) will be able to display it in the local timezone, depending on the timezone settings.

Under normal circumstances adding timezone information like this is a code smell.

Conversions in the UI can be done with various localized formatting extensions, depending on the UI's thread culture info.

Comment: This seems to make the most sense, but how do I display UTC timestamps as local times in the UI? Wouldn't I still have to do a conversion in the front end for that to happen? Then there's also the issue of converting timestamps from UTC to local when they're being displayed in a table.

Comment: Hi, yes; we need more info for that: we need to know which technology you use in your front end / ui.

Comment: It's currently ASP.NET Web Forms. We're planning on moving to MVC, but that may not happen for a while.

Comment: Okay, that's a tricky one. Assuming you set your datagrid or labels somewhere, you can use the `ToLocalTime` option of the `DateTime` object. But it will be bound to the trhead requesting it. In the past we used cookies to determine the clients requested timezone, but that might depend on the actual usage of the application. Preferably, in your case: do it when binding to the ASP controls. Or; maybe ask an additional question about how to localize your web form UI.

Answer (score 1):

You may use ToLocalTime() method to read it time as local time.

Answer (score 0):

for loop is efficient enough for this,
but if you want something in one line, maybe you can try this linq:

```
codes.Select(c => {c.created += 4; return c;}).ToList();
```

The `ToList` is needed in order to evaluate the select immediately due to lazy evaluation.

Comment: I mean, `foreach (var code in codes) { code.created += 4; }` is as much of a oneliner as yours is and less complex (= better readability)

Comment: yes, maybe! but question specifies exactly that not want to use for loops. i thought perhaps looking for advanture and find new ways.